# Can I "unmerge" merged meshes UE4?

Tags: unreal-4, mesh

I set up my character to be modular, by following the [UE4 docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/WorkingwithModularCharacters/index.html).

I used the code at the bottom of the page to implement mesh merging functionality.
It does work well, I can merge meshes runtime.
I use this to add clothes to my characters.

Just wondering, if there is a way to take off clothes, by unmerging stuff:
Something like:

- store added clothes in a TArray or something
- then call a function to remove the desired cloth from the array

Of course, I would like to do it at runtime...

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to go back to your starting mesh than to try to undo a merge operation.

Comment: Yes, removing all, adding all minus undesired ones would work.